# Error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sort'. Trying to test sorting of objects in a class with pytest

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

I have defined a class with <, >, <=, >=, ==, and != defined between members. I want to be able to sort lists of elements via these definitions and get the same set of elements, but in a potentially different order.
In the example used, path12 is .../dir1/file2 etc.  Instead of typical lexiconic order (with the rightmost digit changing quickest and the leftmost slowest) I want the last part of the path to move slowest and the leftmost quickest.  (I'm searching for files and want file names to match, with less emphasis as you go up the directory tree.)
Relevant code in class definition then pytest code is:

```
class BackPath:
    def __init__(self, path_name: str):
        self.full_name = path_name
        self.path = Path(path_name)
        self.parts = self.path.parts
        self.back = list(self.parts[::-1])
        self.name = self.back[0]

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.back > other.back

...
@pytest.fixture
def path11():
    """Return .../dir1/file1.test."""
    # Note windows: "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\ImageProcessing\data\dir1\file1.txt"
    return BackPath("C:/Users/Steve/PycharmProjects/ImageProcessing/data/dir1/file1.txt")

# Similarly for path12, path21, and path22.

@pytest.fixture
def list_of_paths():
    """list(path22, path12, path21, path11)."""
    return [path22, path12, path21, path11]

def test_sort_works():
    assert (list_of_paths.sort(key=lambda x: x.full_name) == [path11, path21, path12, path22])
```

The Attribute error I'm getting is the one for trying to sort a string in place. With the reference to function, I think it might be looking at path11(). I'm new to pytest and @pytest.fixture, so I might have mis-specified the definition or use of the fixture.

As always, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `path11` as a function, instead of as a variable. If its only purpose is to store a string, I recommend changing it to a variable:

```py
path11 = BackPath("C:/Users/Steve/PycharmProjects/ImageProcessing/data/dir1/file1.txt")
```

I noticed you're using pytest decorators, which you can only use on functions... so if you really want to define your paths as functions, you will have to change the way you access them inside `list_of_paths`:

```py
return[path22(), path12(), path21(), path11()]
```

Comment: I don't want the paths as functions.  I want them as objects in my class BackPath.  I assumed that if I defined comparison operators like < and >, I could expect .sort() to work on a list of them.